# Testing For Salmonella in raw eggs

Tags: food-safety, eggs, raw

I purchased eggs from the refrigerator in a local grocery store...When arriving home I missed and left them on the floor in my house in the plastic grocery bag still in the carton for 2 weeks! The temperature in my house stays on 76-78 degrees here in Florida.

Is there a test that I can do here at home to see if the eggs have spoiled or have salmonella, or should I just throw them away? When I found them here I put them in my refrigerator but have not used them.

Comment: With eggs that have been washed and therefore need to be refrigerated, it's not just salmonella you need to worry about if they stay warm

Comment: 2 weeks!!! throw them out.

Answer (score 3):

The FDA [advises no more than 2 hours should pass](https://www.fda.gov/downloads/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/UCM278445.pdf) between purchasing refrigerated raw eggs and putting them back into a refrigerator. 2 weeks exceeds that by 168-fold. Toss those eggs and purchase new ones.

There is no easy at-home test for salmonella, and certainly none as cheap as a carton of eggs. If you want to completely avoid the risk, I would recommend finding a source of pasteurized eggs. Barring that, get new eggs from the store and [follow all FDA advice regarding their storage, handling, and cooking.](https://www.fda.gov/food/resourcesforyou/consumers/ucm077342.htm)

Answer (score 2):

There is no viable test. Even if a microbiologist started culturing your eggs now, it would take several days to find out the microbiological status of the eggs as of today - but several days will have passed in the meantime, so the information won't help you anyway. And the cost of this culturing would be completely ridiculous when compared to the cost of a carton of eggs.

There is no practical way to find out if food is actually dangerous or not. All that's feasible to do is to follow storage guidelines. If you did not, your food is not safe, and nobody can tell you if it will make you sick or not.